# Connect Aeron between two separated machines

Tags: aeron

Is it possible to send messages with aeron between 2 separated machines that are not in the same local network?

If so, how do you connect to the Media driver remotely.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to run a media driver on each machine. The channel for the publication should specify a channel endpoint that is the name/ip of the machine it is sending to. The subscription on the receiving machine will specify its own name/ip in the channel endpoint.